# SonataAdmin: Role only view list and edit. Prevent create, delete

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

SonataAdmin: Role only view list and edit. Prevent create, delete.
Example:
I have group "basic_admin" and role "super_admin".
Basic_admin can only view list and edit. Super_admin can do anything.
So, how to do this?
Thank you! "

Answer (score 0):

The best way seems to be role based security:

http://www.phpassionate.com/2013/05/05/role-based-security-in-sonata-admin/